# Pressing Ctrl + A in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, keypress

Is there a way to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> keys using Selenium WebDriver?

I checked the Selenium libraries and found that Selenium allows key press of special and [function keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key#MS-DOS/Windows) only.

Comment: You can get the answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578768/press-ctrla-to-select-all-content-in-a-page-by-webdriver

Comment: The programming language was revealed in [a comment to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/pressing-ctrla-in-selenium-webdriver#comment15311108_11509778).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One more solution (in Java, because you didn't tell us your language - but it works the same way in all languages with `Keys` class):

```java
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

You can use this to select the whole text in an `<input>`, or on the whole page (just find the `html` element and send this to it).

---

For using Selenium Ruby bindings:

There's no `chord()` method in the [`Keys` class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys.html) in Ruby bindings. Therefore, as suggested by Hari Reddy, you'll have to use Selenium Advanced user interactions API, see [`ActionBuilder`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html):

```ruby
    driver.action.key_down(:control)
                 .send_keys("a")
                 .key_up(:control)
                 .perform
```

Comment: i missed to tell by language. I use ruby with selenium

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work for me. Still i could not copy all the texts in the editor. i am using selenium 2.20 on firefox 3.6 or firefox 11.

Comment: Worked for me with the selenium-webdriver ruby gem, using the firefox driver but this isn't working with the chrome driver.

Comment: Same for me. Works in firefox but not chrome.

Comment: I believe in ruby you can just do `send_keys(:control, "a")`

Answer (score 16):

To click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, you can do it with Actions

```
  Actions action = new Actions(); 
  action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0061')).perform();
```

\u0061 represents the character 'a'

\u0041 represents the character 'A'

To press other characters refer the unicode character table - http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Comment: Don't forget to have keyUp of the CONTROL Key or you will have weird errors in future tests.

Comment: A more complete answer should include `keyUp`. As the OP has not left the building, that should be possible (also verifying that it actually works). You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11507909/edit).

Answer (score 13):

In Selenium for C#, sending `Keys.Control` simply toggles the **Control** key's state: if it's up, then it becomes down; if it's down, then it becomes up. So to simulate pressing **Control+A**, send `Keys.Control` twice, once before sending "a" and then after.

For example, if **we** is an input IWebElement, the following statement will select all of its contents:

`we.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a" + Keys.Control);`

Comment: Thank you.  I've been looking for this.

Comment: Great. By using your comment, In R lang using the Rselenium I get the result of Control+A too. In this case I had to type: `page$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = 'control',"a", key = 'control'))`

Comment: It also works in Python and for several keys (though [the identifiers for the keys are in uppercase](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97716/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.RETURN) and the name of the function from Python is in snake case - `send_keys`). E.g. for Shift + Alt + Y: `send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ALT + "y" + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ALT)`

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(id("anything")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me for my python application, using `driver.send_keys(Keys.TAB)`

Answer (score 3):

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> maps to ASCII code value 1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to 2, up to, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to 26).

Try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace SeleniumHqTest
{
    class Test
    {
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
            IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.Id("an_element_id"));
            char c = '\u0001'; // ASCII code 1 for Ctrl-A
            el.SendKeys(Convert.ToString(c));
            driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is true in a 1980s terminal, but does it also work here?

Answer (score 3):

**For Python:**

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer in C# (if you are C# inclined).

```
Actions action = new Actions(); 
action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).SendKeys("a").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).perform();
```

This answer is almost given [by Hari Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/pressing-ctrl-a-in-selenium-webdriver/11507909#11507909), but I have fixed the case which he'd got wrong on some keywords, added the KeyUp or you get in a mess leaving the control key down.

I've also added the clarification on *OpenQA.Selenium.Keys*, because you may also be using Windows.Forms on the same class as I was an require this clarity.

Lastly, I type "a" because I found that to be the simplest way and I can see no suggestion from the OP that they don't want the simplest answer.

Many thanks to Hari Reddy though as I was a novice in Actions class usage and I was writing many different commands. Chaining them together the way he showed is quicker :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me.

```
WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
textbox.sendKeys("Testing");
textbox.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"A");
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.. and this is better than actions class KeyDown and KeyUp method, facing some wired issue when using actions Key method.to preform keypress actions

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Actions action = new Actions(driver); 

action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

This method removes the extra call ( String.ValueOf() ) to convert unicode to string.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Ruby, you can pass two arguments to `send_keys`

Like this:

```
element.send_keys(:control, 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions action 
    = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(browser);
action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
    .SendKeys("a").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the *Robot* class in Java:

```java
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        d1.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Robot rb = new Robot();
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        // Perform [Ctrl+A] Operation - it works
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

        // It needs to release key after pressing
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: rb means robot? and where you initialize rb ? :)

Comment: @Csanesz: Yes, rb is the instance of Robot

Comment: You can initialize Robot as:    Robot rb = new Robot();

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using C# (Visual Studio 2015) with Selenium:

```
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "A").Perform();
```

You can add as many keys as wanted using (+) in between.

Comment: This not working for me, WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0. C# VS 2019 (I think the VS version doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

#### Java

The *Robot* class will work much more efficiently than sending the keys through Selenium sendkeys. Please try:

Example:

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

To use the above *Robot* class, you need to `import java.awt.Robot;`'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Generally it is better to add some text in your answer to explain better to the person who asked the question: it is not guarantee he understands directly from the code.

Comment: Isn't use of keyDown() required (not a rhetorical question)?