# How can I send keyboard shortcut Alt + Shift + Z (hotkey) with Selenium 2?

Tags: selenium, shortcut, hotkeys

I am trying send a shortcut with Actions.sendKeys, but it isn't working.

```
(New Actions(driver)).SendKeys(Keys.ALT, Keys.SHIFT, "z");
```

Comment: What host language for Selenium? Java?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check this question to refer about this  - *[Pressing Ctrl+A in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Check the answer which uses the **chord method**. In your case, you can do this -

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.SHIFT,"z");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Comment: My words exactly :). Just to note - the OP's solution won't work, because it presses the Alt, Shift and Z keys one by one, not simultaneously.

Comment: So if we have to press all 3 buttons simultaneously, can we use the chord method?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point :). I was just explaining why the OP's original attempt didn't work.

Comment: @Hari But in my case `Z` does not work though `z` works- a case heck!

Comment: chord is not available in the C#, Can you please suggest an answer for the C#. Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done using **Actions keyUp and keyDown** functions.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Actions keyAction = new Actions(driver);
keyAction.keyDown(Keys.ALT).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("z").keyUp(Keys.ALT).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%+z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using JavaScript,

```
Keys.chord(keys)
```

Also, the documentation is at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.SHIFT,"z");` method as suggested in the other/accepted answer, I would suggest you try the Robot framework for using keyboard shortcuts.

You can do something like;

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.delay(3000);


robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
```

I guess this would help sort your problem.