# How to press Ctrl+A to select all content in a page by Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, virtual-keyboard, selectall

I want to select all content by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> from keyboard by using WebDriver with Java. I wrote the following code:

```
Actions actionObj = new Actions(driver);
actionObj.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
         .sendKeys(Keys.chord("A"))
         .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
         .perform();
```

Unfortunately, it did not work. What's the wrong in my WebDriver Java code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To select the whole page:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

cssSelector is faster than `xpath`. So it could be done by using CSSPath also. Below is the way:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me in Chrome on Linux. What may be the reason?

Comment: I get `AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'` error for some reason when I use chord. Any ideas folks?

Comment: @baltusaj You're probably using the wrong Keys. You need to use org.openqa.selenium.Keys

Comment: Long standing issues with this on Mac OS and Chrome driver: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30

Comment: @baltoro in python you simply `send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")`

Answer (score 17):

Try to chord the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keys. The code below is working in my case:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

Comment: yes, this is working nicely. I visited www.google.com and I selected the text of google text box as: driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")); It is working well according to your direction... thanks. I want to select whole page of google. How can I do that?

Comment: I stumbled upon the answer to this due to a bug in some of my automated tests... I used a CSS selector that ended up selecting an element of the page that wasn't an input field (like a div, for example)... when the test sent the CTRL+A to this element it ended up selecting the whole page.

Comment: Complementing the comment above, Webdriver generally tries to emulate the user in the best way it can... What happened when it sent a CTRL+A to an element that wasn't an input is what would happen if we did it manually (clicked anywhere in the page that wasn't an input and pressed CTRL+A).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I sent CTRL+A to a div of the page and whole page was selected. My main goal was to select all. This is good solution Luiz

Comment: I get `AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'` error for some reason when I use chord. Any ideas folks?

Comment: What is the alternate in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Mac users should use Cmnd instead of Control:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service_obj = Service(executable_path="C:/Firefox-Webdriver/geckodriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service_obj)

browser.get('http://localhost:8000/')
browser.get(url)

body = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "c")
```