# How to send "Control + F" keypress action in Python-Webdriver?

Tags: python, automation, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, keypress

I need to open a webpage and send a keypress event (`ctrl + f`) which will move the focus to a text box inside the webpage. Then I need to send a string to that text box.

I have two problems:

- The `ctrl + f` key press event does not work.
- I am not able to locate the element in focus which is a text box element or send a string to that field.

This is the code I am trying:

```
self.driver = self.get_driver()
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
editable = self.driver.execute_script("return document.activeElement")
print(editable.text)
editable.sendKeys("foo")
```

The solution in the other question did not solve my issue. I have provided the solution that worked for me, which is different from the way it works in Java version.

Comment: try `Keys.chord` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578768/how-to-press-ctrla-to-select-all-content-in-a-page-by-selenium-webdriver-using

Comment: This solution worked for me.

        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'f')
    element = self.driver.switch_to_active_element()
    element.send_keys('foo')
    element = self.driver.switch_to_active_element()
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

I needed to find the body of the webpage prior to sending the send_keys action. Also, switch_to_active_element was a simpler way of identifying element in focus instead of using execute_script("return document.activeElement").

Comment: If this question is reopened you should repost your solution with the answer.