# How to copy a field from excel and search for it in a webpage using webdriver/java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need inputs on how to proceed with the below scenario:

1. Copy data from a excel file(For ex: email address)
2. Search for it in a web page
3. if find copy the corresponding data and paste it in another excel file

Can we do this in webdriver with java?

Comment: Yes it can be done using selenium webdriver.What you have tried so far? Share code which you have tried to read data from excel and search on web.

Comment: I just need inputs on how to proceed with this, I have a very rough code ,even if i share that will not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use POI jars
Use getXLcellValue function to get the value in excel
Use setXLCellValue function to set the value in excel

Parameters :-

- xlpath -> Location of your Excel file
- sheetName -> Sheet name in your Excel File
- rowNum and cellNum -> Row and column number where your    data is
  present

  ```
       public String getXLcellValue(String xlpath, String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)
          {
              try{
                  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

                  Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

              Log.info("Get the value from the cell(getXLcellValue)");

                  return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();

          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              Log.info("Error in getXLcellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
          }
          return "";
      }


          //set the value of the cell present in specific sheet

      void setXLCellValue(String xlpath,String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum, String input)
      {
          try{
              FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

              Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

              wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).createCell(cellNum).setCellValue(input);

              FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlpath);

              wb.write(fos);

              fos.close();

              Log.info("Set the value in cell(setXLCellValue)");

          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              Log.info("Error in setXLCellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
          }

      }
  ```

Use first function to retrive data from Excel.
Secondly do opration on web as per your need
Third use set function to set the value in Excel.

You can search on web something like that

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action select= builder
        .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .sendKeys("f")
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
        .sendKeys("ss")
        .build();
select.perform();
```

OR by using robot class(Not recommended )

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnK']")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "f"));
try{
    Robot robot= new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi shubham, please allow me few mins to try this.

Comment: after getting the data from excel cell, how to search for it in a web page?

Comment: It's depends on you and also depend on your data. Suppose if it's a text then use locator "Partial Linktext" to locate your element . Refer this :- http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators

Comment: No, what I'm saying is can we make webdriver to use ctrl+f?

Comment: Yes .. refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578768/how-to-press-ctrla-to-select-all-content-in-a-page-by-selenium-webdriver-using

Comment: as per your request, i accepted it but it not worked for me

Comment: Oh! can you please explain where you are facing issue

Comment: I have added a example that how you search on web page.

Comment: thank you, will try but cannot share the o/p right away because i have to set a property file for another class. Don't know how to do it, but trying