# How to press (down arrow +shift key) button using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

How to press (down arrow +shift key) button using selenium WebDriver?
I need to select options from multi Select box. For that i need to know how to press both keys together. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should make some investigation and try to do it yourself. If you fail, provide your code and we'll try to help you. At least show `HTML` for target select box and programming language you use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to press Ctrl+A to select all content in a page by Selenium WebDriver using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578768/how-to-press-ctrla-to-select-all-content-in-a-page-by-selenium-webdriver-using)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the Robot class in Java you can perform like shown below

```
Robot robot=new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); 
//This will press shift key on keyboard.

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN); 
//This will press the down key on your numpad.

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
//This will release the down key on your numpad.

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
//This will release the shift key.
```

Comment: Actually, `selenium` has `Action Chains` module (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains for `Python`) that allow to perform clicking multiple buttons simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
String multiSelect = Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).sendKeys(multiSelect);
```

You can do it of course in other combinations, too.