# Actions Class in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, keydown, keyup

I am trying to perform the Control+A operation using the Actions class in Selenium using the following query:-

driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");

new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
.build().perform();

However , instead doing Control+A for the contents on the Webpage , it is performing the same operation in the URL bar. Could someone please let me know what is the error here.Moreover the issue what i see is the control stays in the URL bar and it doesnt come down to the Webpage.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578768/how-to-press-ctrla-to-select-all-content-in-a-page-by-selenium-webdriver-using

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with pressing keys in `selenium 3.0` which is reported here [Actions sendKeys UnsupportedCommandException with geckodriver](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2611)

You can try following alternative way to do that -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Narendra, i think the issue was since the control didnt go to the webpage and stayed in the URL bar , it was not happening. Clicking anywhere in the body of the page and doing the action it worked.

Comment: Nice to hear you. If it is helpful, don't forgot to accept the answer.