# How to press keys with ruby programmatically?

Tags: java, ruby, windows

I am in windows environment . I want to launch my hotkeys which has global scope. I am using it with selenium webdriver . With Java I can do something similar in below manner

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
// Robot start writting 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
```

Comment: Then use jruby for fun and profit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-selenium-webdriver