# How can I simultaneously perform 'CTRL + Enter ' in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I simultaneously perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> in Selenium WebDriver?
I tried this one:

```
       body1.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "ENTER");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Check : 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium and, 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   String keysPressed =  Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
   element.sendKeys(keysPressed) ;
```

will do the work for you..

Answer (score 1):

This method uses actions instead of the chord function.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.RETURN).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

webdriver.ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/