# Looking for a way to mimic the "chord" (multi-keypress) function in Perl / Selenium-Remote-Driver

Tags: perl, selenium

Basically I'm looking for a way to send a CTRL + A to a div on a webpage in a Selenium/Perl environment.  It seems like other language drivers have a "chord" function to do it, but the Perl module doesn't have that so far as I can see.  Any ideas?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11509778/176646) to a similar question from a couple of years ago states that there isn't a `chord` function in the Ruby bindings either, but that you can simulate it with key presses. I'm guessing you can adapt that solution to Perl.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do it in the end.  Used AutoIt to get the functionality.  Such shame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) like:

```
# include the WDKeys module
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
.
.
$driver->send_keys_to_active_element(KEYS->{'space'}, KEYS->{'enter'});
```

There's also **send_modifier** method which sends an event to the active element to depress or release a modifier key. So that you could do something as:

```
$driver->send_modifier('Alt','down');
$elem->send_keys('c');
$driver->send_modifier('Alt','up');
```