# Send keys without specifying element in python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page whose source code is not available, but there is a input box where cursor is blinking.

Can i write something into the text box without finding the element. I mean, some way where send key can automatically look for focused inputbox and type input to it.

My code does not work obviously

```
driver.send_keys("testdata")
```

Comment: If the element is active, you could just send individual keystorkes: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11507909/2374517

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Solved it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.send_keys('dummydata')
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Use `actions = ActionChains(driver)` if you face issues on line 2 of the above answer. The author probably has the driver generated within a class object, hence needed self.driver to access it.

Answer (score 18):

If you get error about 'self' in this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.send_keys('dummydata')
actions.perform()
```

just use:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

<s>I don't have comment rights that's why I put this as answer</s>

Edit: Added this enhancement as a comment on the original answer.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(' ')
```

(Which I used to use a space character to scroll through a page)