# Send keys without specifying element in python selenium webdriver (action chains did not work)

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I have a script in which I click a button and the cursor begins blinking. All my attempts at specifying the element via xpath/id/class name to send the keys from have failed. So, I am attempting to just send the keys to where the cursor is blinking.

I've tried a few solutions:

1. [Send keys without specifying element in python selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886927/send-keys-without-specifying-element-in-python-selenium-webdriver)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('dummydata')
actions.perform()
```

This solution did not send any keys at all.

2. Switch to the active element.

```
elem = driver.switch_to.active_element()
elem['value'].send_keys('dummydata')
#OR#
elem.send_keys('dummydata')
```

In this instance, I received error:

```
elem = driver.switch_to.active_element()
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

Not sure what else to try at this point. Baffled at why this is happening.

Comment: Check if the element is inside an `iframe`, if so, [switch to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python?rq=1) before sending the keys.

Comment: Try `elem = driver.switch_to.active_element`  -- that is, don't use the `()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be, that the element may inside an iframe as @Pedro is mentioning.

To get the active element without XPath and other selectors, you can try using javascript:

```
elem = driver.executeScript("document.activeElement")
```

If this still does not work, it's either an iframe or maybe a virtual software textinput (js, canvas, ...). You can play around with some javascript commands in the browser console to check how and what elements are responding.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me through a modal. I was successfully able to click a button inside a modal.

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("document.activeElement")
time.sleep(3)
send=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Send now']")
time.sleep(3)
```