# How to press (ctl+alt+6) by using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to press 3 keyboard buttons together. by using selenium webdriver is it posible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Key press in (Ctrl+A) Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

```
Actions a = new Actions(Driver)
a.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
a.keyDown(Keys.ALT);
a.keyDown(Keys.NUMPAD6);
a.keyUp(Keys.NUMPAD6);
a.keyUp(Keys.ALT);
a.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
a.perform();
```