# Webdriver isn't sending multiple keystrokes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm setting up a bot to do some job's for me but i cant send the Ctrl+Shift+a combination

I tried using the Actions Class but nothing i tried to send Ctrl+a te select everything it is working but not Ctrl+Shift+a i am using this from a extension i thought maybe it isnt triggering the extensions hot key so i wrote a javascript that detects that combination but it isn't showing any sign of life

```
driver.FindElementByTagName("body")
      .SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift + "a");
```

Comment: Is a capital A required? I'm assuming you are using CTRL+A to select all? If so, you don't need the capital A so you can remove the Shift key in the sequence.

Comment: no it isn't a capital a required ,i am not trying to send uppercase a

Comment: Then why are you sending `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift`? You should only need `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "a"`

Comment: Ctrl is working but i need Ctrl Shift and a that is the hotkey i tried Ctrl A just as a test

Comment: Looks like a fairly common issue, here's one https://stackoverflow.com/q/11503736/495455

Comment: since Ctrl+a was working i tried to get the source code of the extension and change the hotkey to ctrl+b from ctrl+shift+a but it wont work i think the keystrokes sent by selenium cant be cought from the extension if anyone has a idea